# My SQL comment while creating table

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to add comment/description to a MYSql table, while creating it? The purpose is to use the information to inform other users about the purpose/use of the table in the software. I know that we can put comments to a column, while creating table,but nothing for the same is available anywhere.

Any help shall be deeply appreciated. Also, do share the query to retrieve the info/comment/description from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had you checked out mysql's manual on [create table statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), you would have found that you can add a `comment` clause to the end of the statement:

> table_option:
>       AUTO_INCREMENT [=] value
>     | AVG_ROW_LENGTH [=] value
>     | [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name
>     | CHECKSUM [=] {0 | 1}
>     | [DEFAULT] COLLATE [=] collation_name
>     | COMMENT [=] 'string'
>
> ...
>
> COMMENT
>
> A comment for the table, up to 2048 characters long.
>
> ...
>
> The comment is displayed as part of the ouput of SHOW CREATE TABLE.
>   The text of the comment is also available as the TABLE_COMMENT column
>   of the MySQL Information Schema TABLES table.
>
> This comment syntax is also supported with ALTER TABLE statements for
>   NDB tables. Keep in mind that a table comment used with ALTER TABLE
>   replaces any existing comment which the table might have had
>   perviously.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    c1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    c2 VARCHAR(100),
    c3 VARCHAR(100) )
ENGINE=INNODB
COMMENT='Whatever'
```